# Is my proof a notable result? If so, where and how do I publish it?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I can prove that given $ε$ chosen arbitrarily small, if $\prod_{p \le p_k} p^{\frac{1}{p-1}} \lt \frac{1 + ε}{e} p_k$ then $∀n\ge p_k∃p∈\mathbb{P} | n \le p \lt (1 + ε)n$.

Actually this result is better than Bertrand's Postulate.
And I've seen [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.4451.pdf) paper which has a worser result.

But how much is this result notable? If so, how and where do I publish it?

**EDIT**

In my first post I've made a huge mistake: I've written a sum instead of a product! Now it's correct.

**EDIT**

By GHfromMO's answer, it's clear that $ε$ has a lower bound. But is this result anyway notable? If so, where and how can I publish it?

Comment: Note that the paper you linked to has not been published in any peer reviewed journal.

Comment: Do you have a value of k for which your product inequality holds?  I am computing for small k and have found none.  Gerhard "Truth Sometimes Comes From Emptiness" Paseman, 2018.02.09.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman For ε = 1, k = 12 is sufficient.

Comment: The problem with your (corrected) result is that it is too restrictive (in my opinion). The conclusion is only interesting if $\varepsilon$ is small, but this requires $p_k$ to be large. However, for $p_k$ large and $\varepsilon$ small, the initial condition fails. This is because the product in the condition is asymptotically $0.5614... p_k$. See my "Added" section.

Comment: @user1582006: Whether a result is interesting enough to publish or not, is an opinion. Mathematics is a social game, not just pure science. Interesting new proofs of classical results do appear from time to time, in journals like the Amer. Math. Monthly. If your proof is really simpler than that of Erdős, then it might be worthwhile to try such a journal.

Comment: It is not really possible to judge the significance or notabliity of the new proof you claim to have found, unless you actually show people what you have done, by writing it up and sending it somewhere, or posting it on a blog

Answer (score 9):

The terms in your sum tend to $1$, therefore your sum is asymptotically $k$ (as $k$ tends to infinity), which is $o(p_k)$. Hence your initial condition holds for $k$ sufficiently large, even if you replace $(1+\varepsilon)/e$ by any positive constant (e.g. by $1/100$).

It is also-well known that for given $\varepsilon>0$ and for $n$ sufficiently large (in terms of $\varepsilon$), there is always a prime number between $n$ and $(1+\varepsilon)n$. In fact it is known that, for $n$ sufficently large, there is always a prime number between $n$ and $n+n^{0.525}$.

**Added.** The OP changed the initial condition from $\sum_{p \le p_k} p^{\frac{1}{p-1}} \lt \frac{1 + ε}{e} p_k$ to $\prod_{p \le p_k} p^{\frac{1}{p-1}} \lt \frac{1 + ε}{e} p_k$. The new condition is false for $\epsilon=1/2$ and $k$ sufficiently large. Indeed, we have
$$\prod_{p \le p_k} p^{\frac{1}{p-1}}=\exp\left(\sum_{p \le p_k}\frac{\log p}{p-1}\right)=\exp\left(o(1)+\sum_{n \le p_k}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}\right).$$
The right hand side is asymptotically $e^{-\gamma}p_k$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant, so the left hand side exceeds $\frac{1.5}{e}p_k$ for $k$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @GH_from_MO  "It is also-well known"? Where can I get a proof of that?

Comment: It's a well-known easy consequence of the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: @user1582006: It follows immediately from the prime number theorem. For any fixed $\varepsilon>0$, the number of primes between $n$ and $(1+\varepsilon)n$ is asymptotically $\varepsilon n/\log n$. For similar results in much shorter intervals, see Section 10.5 in Iwaniec-Kowalski: Analytic number theory.

Comment: @Noam_D._Elkies Ok. But where can I find a proof of that?

Comment: @user1582006: Here is the proof: $\pi(n)=(1+o(1))n/\log n$ and $\pi((1+\varepsilon)n)=(1+\epsilon+o(1))n/\log n$. Now subtract the first expression from the second one.

Comment: @GHfromMo But how do you compute ϵ? With my inequality you can actually find that!

Comment: @user1582006: $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, and $n$ has to be sufficiently large in terms of it. How large $n$ has to be is a different question: there are versions of the prime number theorem with good explicit error terms, which can be used for that purpose. See, for example, http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~ramare/TME-EMT/Articles/Art01.html

Comment: @GHfromMO Please note that for ε = 1, I've a very simple and short proof of Bertrand's Postulate. Do you think that one will be a result worth to publish?

Comment: @GHfromMO You are right. I've made an error by transcribing. Actually it's less than or equal to. See my "edit" on the question.

Comment: @GHfromMO Please reread my question. There was an error.

Comment: @GHfromMO Who said that "n" could not be a prime???

Comment: @user1582006 Your claim is "for every $n>p$ something happens". That includes the possibility that $n$ not be a prime.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Yes. I've made a change. Now I correct this one accordingly.

Comment: Meanwhile, yes, "Bertrand's Postulate" was already proved 100+ years ago by Chebyshev, with a much more elementary proof than any known for the Prime Number Theorem (the key tool is the formula for the prime factorization of $x!$).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I know the simplest proofs of Bertrand's Postulate from Erdos and Ramanujan, but actually my proof is shorter and simpler.